# C# EF - Loading a Collection as child types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my example, I have a `Farm` with `Animals`. The `Animals` within my collection is `<Animal, Dog, Cat>`. `Dog` & `Cat` inherit from Animal.

When loading the`Farm` entity. How can I make Entity Framework load my instances as their respective subtypes `<Animal, Dog, Cat>` instead of `<Animal, Animal, Animal>` ?

```
    var farm = new Farm();
    farm.Animals.Add(new Animal { Name = "Parrot" });
    farm.Animals.Add(new Dog { Name = "Waffles", FavoriteToy = "slinky" });
    farm.Animals.Add(new Cat { Name = "Pitou", FavoriteFood = "Salmon" });
```

[image]
[image]

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.CreateFarm();
        p.Display();

    }
    public void CreateFarm()
    {
        using var context = new MyContext();
        if (context.Farms.FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            var farm = new Farm();
            farm.Animals.Add(new Animal { Name = "Parrot" });
            farm.Animals.Add(new Dog { Name = "Waffles", FavoriteToy = "slinky" });
            farm.Animals.Add(new Cat { Name = "Pitou", FavoriteFood = "Salmon" });

            context.Farms.Add(farm);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        using var context = new MyContext();
        var animals = context.Farms.Include(f => f.Animals).First().Animals;
        foreach (var a in animals)
        {
            var txt = $"animal of type : {a.GetType().Name}";
            if (a is Dog or Cat)
            {
                txt += ". It's a pet!";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(txt);
        }
    }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=c:\\temp\\mydb.db;");
    }
}
public class Farm
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new HashSet<Animal>();
}

public class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? FarmID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Farm? Farm { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public string FavoriteToy { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string FavoriteFood { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are using latest EF core then check this document .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Comment: I've honestly tried all three table-per-* methods and they all deliver the same results. I've even watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaL6DKW1mrg where it's supposed to work out of the box£. clearly i'm doing something wrong, but what

Comment: Well, the type of the collection is `ICollection<Animal>`. What you see is the compile-time type (`Animal`) but the objects in the collections do have their actual types (the subtypes). This is just how types and subtypes work in C#. It's nothing specific to EF. You shouldn't need to know these types because inheritance is a behavioral pattern. See *Liskov's substitution principle*, the L in SOLID.

Comment: If they were their actual types, the `if (a is Dog or Cat)` should be triggered. Which it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here How I configured context.

```
   public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Farm> Farms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=c:\\temp\\mydb.db;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>()
                .HasDiscriminator<string>("AnimalType")
                .HasValue<Animal>("animal")
                .HasValue<Dog>("animal_dog")
                .HasValue<Cat>("animal_cat");
           
        }
    }
    public class Farm
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; } = new HashSet<Animal>();
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int? FarmID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Farm? Farm { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string FavoriteToy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        public string FavoriteFood { get; set; }
    }
```

From above code if you look at the configure.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>()
                .HasDiscriminator<string>("AnimalType")
                .HasValue<Animal>("animal")
                .HasValue<Dog>("animal_dog")
                .HasValue<Cat>("animal_cat");

        }
```

Here few things.

- Discriminator is one column in table and it hold type like dog,cat or animal.
- Then there are three possible type possible. One is Dog, Cat and Animal itself and it configured with HasValue.

Example or demo code is similar to what is in the question so I am not repeating that over here.

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: This actually does the trick. Although the Discriminator actually exists in the DB. Having it manually specified casts the objects